# Ionic 2 open urls in text content with inappbrowser

Tags: javascript, ionic2, inappbrowser

I'm building an app in ionic, it shows a news feed with text content. In the text, there can be url's. I'm using a regex to find url's in the text, and I replace the url's with `<a href="http://example.com"></a>`

Since I don't know the position of the url's in the text, I cannot write code in the html page. What I currently do:

```
urlify(text) {
  var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
  return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
    return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
  });
}
```

Now I want to use the ionic inappbrowser to open these url's. The native inappbrowser does not contain an option to open all url's in the inappbrowser, so I tried a different approach by rendering a button element with `(click)="openUrl(url)"`. This does not work, since there's no binding to the component it seems. The full code of what I tried:

```
urlify(text) {
  var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;

  var url = 'https://www.google.nl';
  var string = '<button (click)="openUrl(\' ' + url + ' \')"> click </button>';
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(string);
}

openUrl(url){
  this.inAppBrowser.create(url);
}
```

How can I achieve all the urls in the text be opened with the inappbrowser?